# Bluetooth start discovery not giving results

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-device-discovery

This is my first app in Android. I am very new to Android and Java. I am kind of expert in iOS/ObjC though. I am learning by doing. So I jumped straight into making an app to connect to a bluetooth device. First step is of course to get a list of the bluetooth device available in range.

Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest...>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application ...
```

Here is my Activity code:

```
private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
       // Unregister broadcast listeners
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }


    /*-------------  ON CREATE ------------------------------*/
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btAdapter =  BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (btAdapter == null) {
            System.out.println ("Bluetooth non support");
        } else {
            System.out.println ("Bluetooth initialized");
        }

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

        IntentFilter filterDevice = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filterDevice);

        if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            String mydeviceaddress = btAdapter.getAddress();
            String mydevicename = btAdapter.getName();

            String status = mydevicename + " : " + mydeviceaddress;
            System.out.println(status);
            System.out.println ("Start discover");
            btAdapter.startDiscovery();
        } else {
            System.out.println ("Not enabled");
            Intent enableBT = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBT, 1);
        }
    }


    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();

            if (action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {
                final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE,
                        BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);
                switch (state) {
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:
                        System.out.println("1");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
                        System.out.println("2");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
                        System.out.println("3");
                        // SCAN HERE
                        btAdapter.startDiscovery();
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON:
                        System.out.println("4");
                        break;
                }
            }

            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action))
            {
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
                System.out.println(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            } else {
                System.out.println("What de fuq");
            }

        }
    };
```

I turned on bluetooth on my android phone, and then running the app shows that log:

> Bluetooth initialized 
>   Start discover

And thats all. Other logs are not printing out. Any idea why? My code seems perfect idk.

EDIT: Screenshot of the Bluetooth module HC-05 being detected by Android.
[image]

Comment: You need to request location permission. https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Comment: I did. You see that in the manifest code i posted above.

Comment: Nvm. I solved it.

Comment: Glad to know that you found the problem. So what was causing it?

Comment: I ditch the connection attempt altogether. I just pair using android settings and connect using btSocket directly.

Comment: @GeneCode you did not. You just declared them. You need to request them on Android 6+

Comment: @Christoper, ok I will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

The other devices may not be in discoverable mode. Make sure they are discoverable.

Comment: i can see the other device if i use android's bluetooth menu in Settings.

Comment: The devices you see in menu are paired devices.

Comment: No not paired. it is in arrow menu.

Comment: Well I am not sure about arrow menu. If you click on "pair new device" in setting, can you see that the other phone is getting displayed in "available devices", any time/all the time? (if not all the time then when).

Comment: Is actually not another phone. it is actually a bluetooth module HC-05. I can see the device in android settings menu when i turn it on. it is just not appearing in the log in my app.

Comment: Before I comment again let me check what is bluetooth module HC-05 :-). But before that one question;  the above code you have written is for an android phone, in which you are running the code right? If it is so, no matter what the other device is it has to be in discoverable mode, when your phone is searching. As it is not a phone, possible that it is always in discoverable mode. Also if possible please post the snapshot of the settings menu, where you see the device.

Comment: Hi. Ok i added the screenshot in Android's settings Bluetooth menu.

Answer (score 0):

If your other device is a bluetooth module, in your case Arduino, right?

If so, check this tutorial describing connection between Android device and HC05 module. 
[bthc-05 to android tutorial](http://arduino-er.blogspot.com/2016/04/android-bluetoothchat-example-link-with.html)

Also, based on this official sample: [google sample - bluetooth chat](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat)

Alternatively, you could also have the following method that makes your device discoverable. And install it on two phones. Then you should be able to discover the phones on each other atleast.

```
protected void makeDiscoverable(){
    // Make local device discoverable
    Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
    discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, DISCOVERABLE_DURATION);
    startActivityForResult(discoverableIntent, DISCOVERABLE_BT_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

Maybe these help!